# JasperReport in Android app

Tags: android, mobile, jasper-reports, report

I'am trying to use jasperreport in my app android, but I can not find an example for this.
It is possible use jasperreport in mobile apps or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't.

It depends on IText, which in turn depends on Java Swing, and that is not available on Android.

Comment: There is another of the same kind tool that is compatible with Android and iOS?

Comment: Not for free. But there are a few commercial libraries that does what you want. Or you can do as I do, send a request to a remote server that does the conversion and serves the result back to your app.

Comment: Perhaps it's too late but there is a library who forks jasper report, this library is http://www.pdfreporting.com/ you can use it to generate reports but I'm facing the problem that I cannot use java bean collections.